# Is it possible to run react native app in background?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am a newbie to React Native and develop my first apps

Here is My app feature:
Check the current location each 10 sec and send the location information to database.

I am using `setinterval` and `@react-native-community/geolocation` to create it.

But finally, I found that the apps can't run in the background.
When the user minimizes the app or turns off the screen or opens another app, the app does not run.

Is there easy way to make react native app in the background??
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Expo, I recommend using BackgroundFetch.

Refernce : https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/?redirected